# xctool tests fail when xcodebuild works - Travis CI

Tags: xcodebuild, travis-ci, xctest, undefined-symbol, xctool

I'm trying to integrate my project into Travis CI, and my builds have failed with the following errors:

**Undefined symbols for architecture i386** and **Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64**

I get these errors for basically every class in my project that hasn't been added to the test target under ***Target Membership***. I could probably solve this by adding ***every single .m file*** as a member of the test target, but that doesn't really make much sense, and my

I've tried to replicate this issue locally by running both of the following commands:

```
xcodebuild -workspace myWorkspace.xcworkspace -scheme MyProjectTests -sdk iphonesimulator build test

xctool -workspace myWorkspace.xcworkspace -scheme MyProjectTests -sdk iphonesimulator build test
```

Using `xcodebuild`, it works, runs, and the tests pass. Using `xctool` the tests fail with the same errors that Travis is using, as Travis uses xctool.

Does anyone have any ideas if there's a best fix for this issue? I assume I missed something somewhere, but I followed the standard Travis *'Getting Started'* walkthrough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After fussing with this a bunch with no luck, it appears as though I'm able to set a custom script for Travis to use instead.. As mentioned, the `xcodebuild` worked, so I added the following to my travis.yml file and everything was all good:

```
script:
 - xcodebuild -workspace myWorkspace.xcworkspace -scheme MyProjectTests -sdk iphonesimulator build test
```

Comment: Hey Mike, don't know how much this is going to help you now, but the [Travis-CI article on objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-6/travis-ci.html) covers this issue, if you add `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO` I believe it will also resolve your problem

Comment: @LouisTur thanks for the heads up, I believe at this point I've actually done that - I'll have to go check. Thanks!